# How many size options are allowed per item?

Tags: cartthrob

Excuse my ignorance but I know very little about Expression Engine and CartThrob.  Of course if I knew it all, I would need to ask this question would I?

So, I'm in ExpressionEngine and I click on CartThrob ->Products ->Store - Products, I click on one of the items listed under the Title column.  It brings up a form where we can enter "Size Options"  In there we can enter the following informaiton.

Option Short Name {option_value}
Option Label {option_name}
Price {price}
Inventory {inventory}
Weight {weight}

My question is how many of these size options can I enter?  I have been told that the limit is 150 but find that difficult believe, but I haven't been able to find documentation to support or refute that claim.

Answer (score 1):

We've set up quite a large site (1500+ products) which uses about 12 different product options - each of which will have between 2 and 8 choices. I think we've used a max of 3 options on any one product. I don't know of a limit, but if it was 150, this should be more than enough for even the largest of stores.

You can always reduce the options you need by naming them a little more generically. So simply *size* or *colour* rather than being too specific would help keep the count down.

If you are even getting close to 150 options, then something has probably gone awry in the site's planning. Either than or you should probably be looking at an enterprise platform :-)